# How to Avoid Motion Blur in SDL 2 Games?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm making a game in SDL 2 and whenever something moves on the screen, it becomes blurry. I tried to catch it on a screen shot but I don't seem to be able to. My question is: is it because of the game or because of my monitor. The blur appears both when I'm running the game on 230 FPS w/o V-Sync and when is caped at 60 with V-Sync. 
PS Monitor refresh rate: 60 Hz

Comment: I haven't tested SDL 2 yet, but if this goes same on SDL 1.2 and SDL 2 for you, then you have a problem with either your sprite texture or your monitor. It's hard to tell without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. It's because of the monitor. Probably because of the refresh rate. If I move a window on the screen I see the same blur.

Comment: That's called ghosting. You probably need to install your graphics drivers.